# Apply for H1B from F1 without OPT

Tags: usa, h1-visa, student-visa

This is a bit weird and complicated question.

I am currently an F1 student in US doing my MS. I got an offer and my Employer is filing H1-B for me ahead of my joining the company (also, I didn't get my joining date).

Now this is where things get complicated, since I didn't know my joining date, I didn't apply for OPT. And thus, my H1-B will be applied without my EAD card.

Question:

1. If my H1-B gets approved before I graduate (say I extended my graduation from May to August), then how is it going to impact my immigration status. And also how it is going to impact my OPT, suppose if I go back to school in the future to pursue my PhD?
2. If my H1-B gets reject before I graduate (say I extended my graduation from May to August), then how is it going to impact my immigration status. And also how it is going to impact my OPT, suppose if I go back to school in the future to pursue my PhD?

Comment: Questions about immigration or moving for extended periods of time (studies or employment, among others) are off-topic. Our sister site, [expatriates.se] Stack Exchange might be a better place to ask.

Comment: You still have time to apply for OPT (within 90 days before and up to 60 days after graduation). I would. Your company should be able to hire you for the OPT, and if you don't get selected for an H-1B this year, they can try again next year. Even if you get an H-1B, you cannot start working until October 1.

Comment: Thanks. I don't have privileges to move this question. If you can, can you move it to the respective site.

Answer (score 2):

In either case it will have no effect on your *current* immigration status. If your F1 status is terminated prior to the H1b start date - you'll have to either go out of country, or change the status to something else (B2, probably). If you want to start working prior the H1b start date - you'll have to apply for OPT and then get the OPT EAD before you can start working.